# Nautilus File Manager closes immediately I open it

Tags: nautilus

When I open Nautilus File manager it closes within a second - this happens whether I use the GUI facility or the Terminal.  When I use the terminal I get the following response:

```
$ sudo nautilus
** (nautilus:71328): WARNING **: 20:54:44.132: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

** (nautilus:71328): WARNING **: 20:54:44.132: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory
Segmentation fault
$ nautilus
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This started happening after I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 this morning. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: why are you using sudo? What happens if you open nautilus without being super user?

Comment: Similar thing happens when I don't use sudo - get "segmentation fault (core dumped)". I tried to fix the problem but have now landed with even bigger problem - can't boot my Lenovo pc.  Made a 20.04 iso (on my Lenovo laptop) and then used that to get into my pc - presently trying to install the iso version of Ubuntu 20.04 alongside the original Ubuntu 20.04 on my pc - could not replace the corrupted (original) Ubuntu 20.04 on the pc.  Now even the "alongside" installation won't work.  The pc is a Lenovo (as is the laptop).  Not sure what to do now.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by:
1) Creating a Ubuntu 20.04 ISO usb stick (from my laptop);
2) Using it (the ISO usb-stick) to wipe my pc hard-disk and re-install Ubuntu. Luckily I had backed-up my hard-drive before "playing around" so could restore my home folder and all subdirectories. Unfortunately some things have changed and I have as yet been unable to solve the issue - for example, I had to re-install Exodus (crypto wallet) but I can't get it to open!